# for in loop in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

I want to get the value of id from scope.getlike={id: "167", like: 3, unlike: 0}.
I tried it in for loop but scope.getlike[likec].id return 'undefined'.How to get value of in controller

```
for (likec in scope.getlike) { 
   console.log(scope.getlike[likec].id);
}
```

Comment: for loop should be used when list of objects or array is to be iterated..in your case you have only one object so you need not to iterate it..you can directly access the object here..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why the loop? You have only one element.

```
console.log(scope.getlike.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AngularJS `forEach` like this:

```
angular.forEach(getlike, function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.id)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

scope.getlike is a object {id: "167", like: 3, unlike: 0}. 
You are looping through all properties in this object: id, like, unlike.

```
* console.log(scope.getlike[id].id) => null because scope.getlike[unlike] is "167". "167"[id] is null
* console.log(scope.getlike[like].id) => null because scope.getlike[unlike] is 3. 3[id] is null
* console.log(scope.getlike[unlike].id) => null because scope.getlike[unlike] is 0. 0[id] is null
```

If you want to get the id of this object, simply use `scope.getlike.id`